# Linq distinct - Count

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking to perform a query on an example list of objects

```
Date     Username

01/01/2011 james
01/01/2011 jamie
01/01/2011 alex
01/01/2011 james
02/01/2011 matt
02/01/2011 jamie
02/01/2011 alex
02/01/2011 james
02/01/2011 james
02/01/2011 lucy
02/01/2011 alex
03/01/2011 james
03/01/2011 bob
03/01/2011 bob
03/01/2011 james
03/01/2011 james
04/01/2011 alex
04/01/2011 alex
04/01/2011 alex
```

I want to use linq to query the list of dates with the number of unique user logins.

For example:

```
01/01/2011 - 3
02/01/2011 - 5
03/01/2011 - 2
04/01/2011 - 1
```

I have tried as tested a number of linq statements but none of these are giving me the desired result. The closest I have got is giving me the distinct dates but with a count of all the users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add those LINQ statements you tried - then we can see why they went wrong.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
logins
  .GroupBy(l => l.Date)
  .Select(g => new
  {
    Date = g.Key,
    Count = g.Select(l => l.Login).Distinct().Count()
  });
```

Comment: I'm new to Linq and I'm wondering how you would write this in Linq query syntax in stead of Linq method syntax.

Comment: @comecme I realize you left this comment ages ago but check out my translation to method syntax below.

Comment: Im afraid your code will always return Count=1, thats because you added the Disctinct() and will make the to count one element. If you remove that, you will have the quantity of elements. Hope this helps!!! ;)

Comment: For example, for some source array [1, 1, 2]: distinct count = 2, count = 3. Obviously, nothing of them isn't equal to 1. We do really need distinct there if we need to calculate unique logins. Using just Count will give wrong number (total logins, not unique).

Comment: Can you help with code to print only the result which count is maximum here i.e 02/01/2011 - 5?

Comment: Simple option - just add `.OrderByDesc(l => l.Count).First()`

Comment: Much like @GabrielAndrésBrancolini said, removing the 'Distinct()' will give you what you're after. Kept getting Count = 1 myself, but I'd run a SQL query and get actual counts.. That's the gotcha, since you've already got the distinct grouping, you just need the count.

Comment: Without distinct it gives total login session count for this date. Even if they were for the same user. With distinct - it gives count of users who logged in in each date. Probably, you have slightly different data structure / target number that topic starter

Comment: It would be nice if LINQ included a `CountDistinct` function, equivalent to `COUNT(DISTINCT <expr>)` in SQL.  Then you would be able to rewrite the penultimate line as `Count = g.CountDistinct(l => l.Login)`.  I think people would naturally use the function for this purpose if it existed.

Answer (score 21):

I realize this is an ancient question but I ran across it and saw the comment about wanting method syntax and couldn't help myself to answer it...  I **may** have a coding disorder.

In query syntax it looks like this...  note that there is no query syntax for `Distinct` and `Count`

```
from l in logins
group l by l.Date into g
select new
{
    Date = g.Key,
    Count = (from l in g select l.Login).Distinct().Count() 
};
```

For a side by side comparison to the original method syntax (which personally I like better) here you go...

```
logins
  .GroupBy(l => l.Date)
  .Select(g => new
  {
    Date = g.Key,
    Count = g.Select(l => l.Login).Distinct().Count()
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my comment.

Answer (score 14):

Can be done within single GroupBy call,

```
  var Query = list.GroupBy(
                 (item => item.DateTime),
                 (key, elements) => new  { 
                                          key = key,
                                          count = elements
                                                  .Distinct()
                                                  .Count()
                                         }
                 );
```

Comment: this is the best answer.  Thanks @naveen

Comment: it will give wrong result (total session count per day, not unique usernames per day)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this maybe?

```
var list = new List<MyClass>(new[] {
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), Username = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "matt" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "jamie" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "lucy" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), Username = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), Username = "bob" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), Username = "bob" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), Username = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), Username = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), Username = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), Username = "alex" }
    });

list.GroupBy(l => l.Date, l => l.Username)
    .Select(g => new { 
                Date = g.Key, 
                Count = g.Distinct().Count() 
            });
```

Comment: Ahh dam it I was so clost, thank you I will look into implementing this shortly. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @aspect - actually this gives you the date with the associated number of unique user logins, from your question do you want to group the dates with the same number of unique user logins as well? if that's what you want, then just add another group by after the select by the count and you're there!

Comment: This seems to be the best solution we have!  Initially I was grouping twice, but didn't really like having to do this.  This is so straightforward in SQL, but the best way in LINQ isn't so obvious.

For everyone's benefit: If you're going to write dates as strings in code, you should use ISO format.  This makes sure the interpretation doesn't depend on locale.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to group twice, check the sample

```
          var dist = listLogins.GroupBy(d => d.date + d.Username)
              .Select(x => x.First())
              .GroupBy(d => d.date).Select(y => new { date = y.Key, count = y.Count() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is need of Distinct count in Oryol's answer. The groupup automatically picks distinct keys and it can be accessed as g.key

```
logins
  .GroupBy(l => l.Date)
  .Select(g => new
  {
    Date = g.Key,
    Count = g.Select(l => l.Login).Count()
  });
```

Comment: I can't see that this would work.  Your code groups only by Date, not by Login.  Without Distinct, it would surely count the total number of logins each day, not the number of distinct users who logged in each day?