# entity framework linq distinct and count occurrences

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I did my googling and after trying out the answered about distinct select and count on SO, it didn't work for my case.

[Linq distinct - Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884462/linq-distinct-count)

So basically I merged multiple tables based on the ID, and I have various other columns as well somethings like this:

```
ID     TIME     LOC     DEVICE#     MagVal
1      9122     AB      1          .88
1      9122     AB      1          .88
1      9122     AB      2          .88
2      9133     CD      1          .875
2      9133     CD      2          .875
2      9133     CD      3          .876
```

So I want it to give me 2 lines which is

```
ID     TIME     LOC     DEVICE#     MagVal
1      9122     AB      2          .88
2      9133     CD      3          .875 (This MagVal could be varied)
```

Comment: So, what is not working?

Comment: I would like to use distinct() but the EF generate a APPLY sql. The database we use is Oracle so there is a conflict. I decided to write a view instead and it work pretty well.

Comment: I am not aware how good EF support Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I can think

```
yourList.GroupBy (l =>l.ID )
    .Select (l =>new{
    ID=l.Key,
    TIME=l.First ().TIME,
    LOC=l.First ().LOC,
    Max=l.Max (x =>x.Device ),
    MegVal=l.Min(x=>x.Magval)
    });
```