# Getting Distinct count from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to find the number of unique dates in my list.

```
 IEnumerable<T>


public int CountUniqueDate()
        {
            return _items.DistinctBy(i => i.DateMeasured).Count();
        }
```

I think, this function will tell me the count of the unique dates in the list.

Now, from the other file, I try to retrieve the value

Either I want the count or the condition which will tell whether it is one or not.

So I try this to check whether the count is 1 or not.

But, here i get compilation error.
If I do `var ans`, then I get a full list.

```
List<T> li;

bool ans= li.Where(x => x.Measures.CountUniqueDate() == 1);
```

Can anyone please help me.

I wanna check, if the CountUniqueDate returns value 1 or not.

Comment: I may be wrong but you may be looking for this - [Linq distinct - Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884462/linq-distinct-count?rq=1)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your second block of code?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you need the second block of code to do.  What is it trying to do?  Do you need a list of elements where `Measures.CountUniqueDate() == 1`?  Do you need to know if any of the items `Measures.CountUniqueDate() == 1`?  Or do you need something else?

Comment: I wanna check, if the CountUniqueDate returns value 1 or not.

Comment: Where does _items come from in CountUniqueDate()? Is it a member of the class that CountUniqueDate() is defined in?

Answer (score 2):

The [WHERE CLAUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesnt return a boolean but an IEnumerable(Of TSource)

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to check if the there is one with count = 1 or not you might use

```
bool ans= li.Any(x => x.Measures.CountUniqueDate() == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to be an extension method like this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int CountUniqueDate(this List<Measure> items)   //<= measure is your T type
    {
        return items.DistinctBy(i => i.DateMeasured).Count();
    }
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
List<Measure> li = YourData;

bool ans= li.CountUniqueDate() == 1;
```