# GroupBy in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have one `favoriteTalent` Table

```
FavoriteTalentID                         TalentID             FavoriteID

101                                      54760                        1

102                                      54633                        1

103                                      54979                        1

104                                      54939                        9

105                                      54551                        9

106                                      54630                        3

107                                      54992                        3

108                                      54778                        7

109                                      60293                        7

110                                      53336                        4
```

I want to groupby the Favorite ID,Means i have to find out How many talentids are in specific `FavoriteID`

Like `FavoriteID` 1 has 3 `TalentID`

This is the query I have written, but output is not perfect.

I want to `GroupBy` the `FavoriteID`. That means I have to find out How many `TalentIDs` are in specific `FavoriteID`

```
var q = db.FavoriteTalents.Where(r => r.Favorite.CDUserID == UserID    
        ||r.Favorite.CDUserID == 0).GroupBy(t =>
new { t.TalentID, t.FavoriteID }
).Select(r => 
new { 

TalentID = r.Key.TalentID,
count = r.Count(),
CDUserID = r.FirstOrDefault().Favorite.CDUserID,
Title = r.FirstOrDefault().Favorite.Title}).ToArray();

return JsonResult(q);
```

Comment: You want to groupby the `FavoriteID` but you groupby `TalentID` and `FavoriteID` instead? Am I missing something or is that clearly your error?

Answer (score 1):

You should group your collection by Favorite Id and then iterate groups to count distinct TalentIDs:

```
var q = db.FavoriteTalents
            .Where(r => r.Favorite.CDUserID == UserID || r.Favorite.CDUserID == 0)
            .GroupBy(t => t.FavoriteID)
            .Select(r => new { FavoriteID = r.Key, Count = r.Select(grouped => grouped.TalentID).Distinct().Count() })
            .ToArray();
```

[GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) returns collection of IGrouping with key selected by selector from method parameter and collection of source objects with same result of selector function.

There is the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884462/linq-distinct-count).

**UPDATE**

To add "empty" Favorits to the result list you should iterate Favorits table:

```
var q = db.Favorites
            .Where(f => f.CDUserID == UserID || f.CDUserID == 0)
            .GroupBy(f => f.FavoriteID, f => f.FavoriteTalents)
            .Select(r => new { FavoriteID = r.Key, Count = r.SelectMany(grouped => grouped).Select(ft => ft.TalentID).Distinct().Count() })
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: You want to count unique values of TalentID per each FavoriteID filter by user Id (plus incomprehensible for me r.Favorite.CDUserID == 0), right? If yes then here is your code, otherwise I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Its working.But i also want that favoriteID which doesnt have any TalentID.

Comment: @AjaySingh for this scenario you should iterate your "Favorites" table instead of "FavoriteTalents" because Favorits without Talents will not have any rows in FavoriteTalents table.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
foreach (string str in db.FavoriteTalents.GroupBy(c => c.FavoriteID)
                       .Select(group => new
                       {
                          fID = @group.Key,
                          Count = @group.Count()
                       }).OrderBy(x => x.fID).Select(item => String.Format("{0} ---> {1}", item.fID, item.Count)))
                     //Or even better with string interpolation : item => $"{item.fID} ---> {item.Count}"
{
     MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

Result is:

> 1 ---> 3
>
> 9 ---> 2
>
> 3 ---> 2
>
> 7 ---> 2
>
> 4 ---> 1