# ordering based on count of values in column when getting distinct values

Tags: linq

```
var acts = new List<MyClass>(new[] {
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), acty = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "matt" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty  = "jamie" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "lucy" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2011"), acty = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), acty = "bob" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), acty = "bob" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2011"), acty = "james" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), acty = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), acty = "alex" },
        new MyClass { Date = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2011"), acty = "alex" }
    });
```

To get distinct values from a list I'm using the following code..

var dacts = acts.Select(o => o.acty).Distinct().ToList();

I would like some help in ordering dacts based on acty count descending.

I have viewed [Linq distinct - Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884462/linq-distinct-count) and it is different from my requirement.

The above question gets distinct values of one column and distinct count of another column.

But, in my case I want distinct values of a column ordered by the count of the same column

So, I want my answer to be..

james, alex, bob, jamie, lucy, matt

Comment: *I want distinct values of a column ordered by the count of the same column* Did you even try to adapt the code in the duplicate to your own situation? It's nothing but filling out the right property names.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dacts = acts.Select(o => o.acty).Distinct().OrderByDescending().ToList();
```

try this one.

```
 var distinctNames = acts.GroupBy(m => m.acty).Select(grp => new { name = grp.Key, count = grp.Count() }).OrderByDescending(k => k.count).ToList();
```

Comment: order by descending on not the values of acty but count of values of acty

Comment: what do you mean acty values? Is acty an class type?Show me your code.

Comment: acty is an element (col) in acts ienumerable