# Check if gridview column on each row has the same values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i check if grid-view column on each row has the same values.

what is the condition that will be applied on below code.

**Code**

```
int y = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridreq.Rows)
{
    string catid = row.Cells[2].Text;
    if (//condition)
    {
        y = y + 1;

    }
}

if (y == 0)
{

//code

}
else
{
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than a `foreach` inside your `foreach`, there is no feasible way to check a row's value against **all** other row's values. Some workarounds:

Maybe you could check against the first value?

```
int y = 0;
var checkItem = gridreq.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridreq.Rows)
{
    string catid = row.Cells[2].Text;
    if (catid == checkItem)    //or use String.compare here
    {
        y = y + 1;

    }
}
```

Another way is to check the value against that of the row **before** it.

```
int y = 0;
string catidCheck = "";
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridreq.Rows)
{
    string catid = row.Cells[2].Text;
    if (catid == catidCheck)    //or use String.compare here
    {
        y = y + 1;
    }
    catidCheck = catid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this with a [Linq distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884501/781965):

```
int y = gridreq.Rows.Select((row) => row.Cells[2].Text).Distinct().Count()
```

Then I guess your condition later would be `if (y == 1)`.