# Linq to SQL get distinct records grouped by date

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get a list of distinct "customer type id" records for each each 24 hour period and add them to a list.

Say my data structure is like

```
DATE        TYPEOF CUSTOMER    CUSTOMER TYPE ID
31-10-2013  GUEST              3
31-10-2013  REGISTERED         4
31-10-2013  MANAGER            2
30-10-2013  GUEST              3
30-10-2013  REGISTERED         4
30-10-2013  MANAGER            3
```

In linq to sql I want to get all the records for each day (24 hour period) then get a distinct count of each "customer type id"

I have made start but do not know how to proceed.  How can I do this?

```
var results = _customerTable.GroupBy(c => new {Date = c.Date.Date}).....
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884462/linq-distinct-count

Comment: _customerTable.GroupBy(c => new { c.Date.Day, c.Date.Hour }).Select(g => new { Day = g.Key.Day, Hour = g.Key.Hour, Count = g.Count() });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following sample code:

```
var results = _customerTable.GroupBy(c => new {c.Date, c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID}).Select(g => new {g.Key.Date, g.Key.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID, MyCount = g.Count()});
```

using this way you can get number of recors per `Date` and `CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID`.

Comment: OK great thank you.  So how would I do this for each 24 hour period?

Comment: You can write a windows console application and use windows task manager to schedule it to run every 24 hours at the prespecified time moment

Comment: No I mean to loop through the table for every 24 hour period (day) then add the results to a list