# C# show string once with amount in numbers of the selection in Foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, foreach, containskey

So i am making a mailfunction and im having an issue showing the data the way i want it to show.

This is my code(editted to show only the issue im having):

```
public string Formatsfunction(List<Metadata> mmds)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> formatNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (Metadata mmd in mmds)
    {
        var type = mmd.Format.Type;
        var found = formatNumber.ContainsKey(type);

        if (found == true)
        {
            formatNumber[type]++;
        }
        else
        {
            formatNumber[type] = 1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return null;
}

private string MeldingInformatie(string impact, string type, List<Metadata> mmds)
{
    var temp = Formatsfunction(mmds);
    var formats = mmds.Select(mmd => mmd.Format.Type +"("+temp+")");
    ...
}
```

What i want it to do is:

If there are multiple of the same types in the Dictionary write it like:

Lion(3) Bear(2) Fish(8) Koala(12) etc.

I think i already got a good start going but am not sure what to do next.

Comment: What isn't working?  When you debug, where does the code first fail?

Comment: Actually your code looks fine so far (if you would avoid comparing `bool`s to `true`)...what _exactly is_ your issue?

Comment: It looks like you maybe didn't paste all the relevant code, Senner .P

Comment: I see you used linq in your last method... you might consider using something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884501/1579626

Comment: Ahhh, is this about how to build a string out of the `formatNumber` dictionary?

Comment: ...which looks empty to me, @RenéVogt.

Comment: Why is the method returning null?  `return null;`

Comment: You are passing a `List<Metadata>` to the function and expecting a `string` from it. What exactly is this string representing?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this:

Returning null is very useless. You need to return the dictionary and use that to format the string. Just select the keys (which are the types) and format it with the value. Use string.Join to combine all types to one string.

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Formatsfunction(List<Metadata> mmds)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> formatNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (Metadata mmd in mmds)
    {
        var type = mmd.Format.Type;
        var found = formatNumber.ContainsKey(type);
        if (found == true)
        {
            formatNumber[type]++;

        }
        else
        {
            formatNumber[type] = 1;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    return formatNumber;
}
private string MeldingInformatie(string impact, string type, List<Metadata> mmds)
{
    var temp = Formatsfunction(mmds);

    // (String interpolation is used)
    var formats = temp.Keys.Select(type => $"{type}({temp[type]})");

    return String.Join(" ", formats);
```

---

What does impact do? It might not solve all the problems, but might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ's [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx)  you can write the whole method like:

```
public string Formatsfunction(List<Metadata> mmds)
{
    return string.Join(" ", 
               mmds.GroupBy(mmd => mmd.Format.Type, (type, g) => $"{type}({g.Count()})"));
}
```

This groups the elements in `mmds` by their `Format.Type` properties and creates a string containing `Type(count)` pairs.

Comment: The Op wants a dictionary.

Comment: @jdweng why do you think that? he wanted a string, he already created the dictionary himself, as you can see in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! Combining all the knowledge you guys have given me i fixed the problem. For those interested the answer was:

```
  public string Formatsfunction(List<Metadata> mmds)
    {
       Dictionary<string, int> formatNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (Metadata mmd in mmds)
        {
            var type = mmd.Format.Type;
            var found = formatNumber.ContainsKey(type);
            if (found == true)
            {
                formatNumber[type]++;

            }
            else
            {
                formatNumber[type] = 1;
            }
        }
        var temp = formatNumber
            .OrderByDescending(p=>p.Value)
            .Select(mmd => mmd.Key +" ("+ mmd.Value+")");
        string keyvalues = string.Join(", ", temp);
        return keyvalues;
    }
    private string MeldingInformatie(string impact, string type, List<Metadata> mmds)
    {
        var temp = Formatsfunction(mmds);

        var formats = mmds.Select(mmd => mmd.Format.Type +"("+temp+")");
        var trackTrace = mmds.Select(mmd => mmd.TrackTrace);
        string messageTypes = string.Join(", ", formats);
     }

Output is now: Lion(8), Fish(7), Koala(6), Seagull(5), etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
            Dictionary<string, int> formatNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
                {"Lion",3},{"Bear",2},{ "Fish",8}, {"Koala", 12}};

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", formatNumber.AsEnumerable().Select(x => string.Format("{0}({1})", x.Key, x.Value)).ToList()));
```

Comment: the `AsEnumerable()` call is not necessary. `Dictinionary<TKey, TValue>` already is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: Also, from `If there are multiple of the same types in the Dictionary write it like: 

Lion(3) Bear(2) Fish(8) Koala(12) etc.` I'd say the OP want's the Dictionary to contain a number of Lions, for instance, and total them.

Comment: @spodger the wording of the question is surely very vague, but I think the intention (there are multiple enries with the same `Format.Type` in the `List<Metadata>` and OP wants a string containing each of these types with a number of occurences) is pretty clear.

Comment: @RenéVogt, I agree, but the answer is just associating the string "Lion" with the number 3. Actually, I'm starting to doubt I understand what the OP wants. :-)